# Code works independently but not as part of the whole program

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which:

1. Creates a new workbook
2. Imports a .csv file
3. formats the data (splits consol data into individual sheets and other operations)
4. Exports the individual sheets into different workbook.

The macro runs perfectly well until step-4.

I get a compile error* at step-4.

When I saved the workbook after step4 as another workbook and then run only step-5. It works well.

I tried both formats .xls and .xlsx while creating the newbook, but the error persists.

I am unable to get to the root cause of the error.

Appendix:

Code used to create a new workbook

```
Sub AddNew()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim thisWb As Workbook
    Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=thisWb.Path & "\FA Registers by Location.xlsx"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Code used to export individual sheets into workbooks (step-4)

```
Sub SplitWorkbook()
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & xWb.Name & " " & DateString
MkDir FolderName
For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        Select Case xWb.FileFormat
            Case 51:
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56:
                FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else:
                FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
        End Select
    End If
    xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

3. Compile error at DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")

[image: Compile Error]

Please note that the complete code isn't included. If you want to look at any part of the code, please ask.

Comment: What is step-4 and step-5?

Comment: @R, step-4 is the export code. Edited my question. There is no step-5. Thanks

Comment: `DateString` is undeclared even though the other variables are, but the error message is not about an undeclared variable, so you are not using Option Explicit. Use Option Explicit and check if you have MISSING elements in Tools - References.

Comment: I am using Option Explicit. If I delete the DateString from the code, the next error that I get is at 

MkDir FolderName

Comment: If you are using Option Explicit, then you have something called `FolderName` that is not in fact a string variable. You then also have something called `xFile` which is also not declared in that sub. In any case search around for declarations of `FolderName`.

Comment: You've said you're using Option Explicit.  Where is DateString declared?  I've tried snippets of your code and defined DateString as String and everything through Mkdir worked.  I have Excel (Office 365/2016 version).  You should also declare FolderName as string.

Comment: guys, there is no problem with the export code. As i mentioned in my question. The code runs fine when I save the generated workbook as a different file and then run the code. The errors come up when this macro is run in the program after 7 other macros.

Comment: `The code runs fine when I save the generated workbook as a different file and then run the code` - which is because the different file does not have that thing called `FolderName`?

Comment: @GSerg to me this sounds very much like one of the other 7 macros is named `Format`.

Comment: @Majid the problem is we cannot recreate the issue with the code you supplied.  you state: "The errors come up when this macro is run in the program after 7 other macros".  So supply the 7 other macros as they introduce the error.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, Good catch. I had another macro named format. Changed the name and the code runs but throws another error. I'll try debugging it myself. Thanks for the help, man.

Comment: @Sorceri, I didn't want to have too much of code in the question. I renamed the macro which was called "Format" and was able to get rid of the errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
> ```

That line means to invoke the `VBA.Strings.Format` function, right? Try fully-qualifying it:

```
DateString = VBA.Strings.Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
```

If this solves your problem, you are a victim of *identifier shadowing*, and there's a `Format` function somewhere in-scope, that doesn't have the same number of arguments.

VBA resolves identifiers in the following order:

1. Within the current scope/procedure
2. Within the current module
3. Within the current project
4. Within the referenced libraries, in the order they appear in the *add/remove references* dialog

So if you have a `Public Sub Format()` somewhere in your project, then any unqualified `Format` call will be resolved to that `Format` procedure, and any call sites that mean to invoke `VBA.Strings.Format` will throw the very compiler error you're seeing - because the arguments provided don't match with the arguments defined in the resolved `Format`'s signature.

So you have two options:

1. Rename your `Format` macro/function/whatever to something else
2. Use fully-qualified member calls everywhere

Note that this is one of the many things [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (an open-source VBIDE add-in project I manage) can warn you about:

[image: "Shadowed declaration" Rubberduck inspection result]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to export the files now.

Comment: @Majid note that if by chance your `Format` macro would have taken 2 string parameters, the code would have compiled, but likely wouldn't have produced the correct results. These bugs can be excruciatingly hard to find - hence the shameless plug for my add-in here, I hope readers won't mind.

Comment: I used the first option to resolve the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: you are right. It compiles but gives unexpected results. Exports the sheets in my tool not the workbook containing 50 sheets. 

I am unable to install your plugin because of restrictions placed by company on installations.

Comment: @Majid FYI if it's any relevant or helpful, the installer doesn't require administrator privileges and can install per-user. Don't install it under-the-radar against company policies, but know that if the restrictions are about admin privs then v2.2 (latest, and subsequent 2.2.x pre-release builds) can be installed without worrying about that.